# Correct usage of fine-uploader Initial File List / getInitialFiles() with PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, fine-uploader

I have successfully set up an environment where files get uploaded to a specified PHP folder and can also be deleted by the user, so the basic set up mainly using the [provided example php server](https://github.com/FineUploader/php-traditional-server) code works.

However, the getInitialFiles() method is not really implemented in the example, and I'm struggling to get it working.

This is what is defined in [handler.php](https://github.com/FineUploader/php-traditional-server/blob/master/handler.php):

```
public function getInitialFiles() {
    $initialFiles = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5000; $i++) {
        array_push($initialFiles, array("name" => "name" + $i, uuid => "uuid" + $i, thumbnailUrl => "/test/dev/handlers/vendor/fineuploader/php-traditional-server/fu.png"));
    }
    return $initialFiles;
}
```

So basically this function simply puts dummy files into the array and returns them - so far, this also works.

I am struggling with displaying all files within my defined upload-directory. Since the handler.php creates sub-folders named by the UUID of the uploaded item, I can't simply print all file names within the upload directory, but would need to access those directories and then scan the files. Easy enough, but in the end I am required to implement a certain logic for already existing files on the prod environment, hence I try to understand what exactly is going on. The tough part is, that there are several files already existing in a folder structure, which would need to be displayed by the FineUploader. Even if I get hold of the file, I wouldn't know how to correctly access a file, not knowing it's UUID.

Further, I wouldn't know how to correctly send parameters to the getInitialFiles endpoint - for example a starting directory or an file id prefix. All my tries to enhance this method horribly failed.

So here are my concrete questions:

1. is it somehow possible to access existing files, which were not uploaded via FineUploader on my server?
2. how can I correctly access those files, given the example that I want to display all files in the folder (f.e.) uploads/:id/ (which holds files 1.png, 2.png, calc.xls) .. where :id is a parameter sent while setting up the fineUploader instance on my .php site?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> is it somehow possible to access existing files, which were not uploaded via FineUploader on my server?

I don't know. That's entirely dependent on your code/environment.

> how can I correctly access those files

I don't know. That's entirely dependent on where/how you store them.

You shouldn't need to "access" these files. You just need to return information to Fine Uploader that describes them. You should have a database with this information.

As the [documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/session.html#server) states, the JSON you return to Fine Uploader when asked for the initial file list...

> must be a JSON array containing Objects for each file to be fed into the uploader.

In PHP, you'll return something like this, which represents only the required properties for a traditional endpoint environment:

```
json_encode(array(array("name" => "foo", "uuid" => "abc123"), array("name" => "bar", "uuid" => "abc124")))
```

Above, you are instructing Fine Uploader to represent two specific files in the initial list of files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ray! Regarding existing files: I haven't seen the usage like this in any examples or documentation, my naive approach was that I could list all files in a certain directory to be displayed within my fineUploader UI. My problem is, that those (previously existing) files don't have an uuid, so I can't properly describe them as a JSON object. Regarding access of files: I would like to open/delete those files from within the fineUploader UI, if possible. Regarding JSON response: this point is clear to me, the problems are more of php-nature (-> next comment ;))

Comment: So the question is how to call the getUUID() method described in the documentation (http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#getUuid), how would I have a file ID from previously existing files? This means that I need to create a DB table containing path/filename and a custom UUID and/or ID used by the fineUploader, there is no way of "simply" reading files from a directory and display them in the fineUploader? The documentation on the Initial File List has quite some potential for improvements, like a small working example, this would really help. :)